# Display jquery val() automaticly summing values

Tags: jquery

I have a default price and i am multiplaying that value by user choice, it shows the value only after refresh, is it possible to show automaticly sum?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#order-rezultats").text($("#price").val() * $("#quantity").val());
});
```

html

```
<div class="row order">
    <label>Order:</label>
        Price: <input type="text" name="price" value="10" id="price" disabled />
        Count: <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity" />
        = <span id="order-rezultats"></span> Ls
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just Use  `keyup` Rest Your code is working fine

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function() {

  $("#order-rezultats").text($("#price").val() * $("#quantity").val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6c77g/

Comment: is there a change that it already shows default values summ? This time it doesn`t show anything when opening the page, only after submitting value..

Comment: Use both keyup and ready function(your code also).with this it will display result on page load also.  http://jsfiddle.net/6c77g/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `input` event to handle the things right,

```
$('#quantity').on('input', function () {
    var value = parseFloat($("#price").val()) * parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
    $("#order-rezultats").text(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
});
```

Here we have used [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to handle NAN values.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fg7cu/)

Answer (score 2):

keyup is good:

```
$(function() {
    $("#quantity").on('keyup', updatePrice);  
    updatePrice();  
})


function updatePrice() {
    $("#order-rezultats").text($("#price").val() * $("#quantity").val());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` returns string . first you convert string to float value or integer

```
    $('#quantity').keyup(function() {

       var price = parseFloat($("#price").val());
       var quantity = parseInt($("#quantity").val());

       $("#order-rezultats").text(price * quantity);

   });
```